# Polymer. Update view after model changed

Tags: polymer

This is a common question in Polymer about updating view when model was updated (answer is to use this.set or this.push Polymer methods).

But when I have two elements:

First element:

```
properties:{
  items: {
    type: Array
  }
},

someFunction: {
  this.push('items', {'Name': 'something'});
}
```

Second Element has property which is bound to 'items' from first element

```
ready: function(){
    this.items = firstElement.items;
}
```

I would like second element 'items' to be updated when 'items' updated on firstElement. I can't manually notify secondElement, because of app restrictions.

So for now I see (in devTools) that model of second element is correct ('items' contains objects), but view isn't updated.

How to update it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set notity on the property of the first element to receive changes outside of the element itself

```
properties:{
  items: {
    type: Array,
    notify: true
  }
},
```

then, in secondElement you can

```
<firstElement items="{{items}}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Let Polymer's [two-way binding](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding#two-way-bindings) handle the notifications for you.

Consider two elements, `x-foo` and `x-bar`, in a container element, `x-app`.

1. In `x-foo`, declare `items` with `notify:true` so that its changes would be propagated upward.

   ```
   Polymer({
     is: 'x-foo',
     properties: {
       items: {
         type: Array,
         value: function() { return []; },
         notify: true
       }
     }
   });
   ```
2. In `x-app`, bind `x-foo`'s `items` to `x-bar`'s.

   ```
   <dom-module id="x-app">
     <template>
       <x-foo items="{{items}}"></x-foo>
       <x-bar items="[[items]]"></x-bar>
     </template>
     <script>
       Polymer({ is: 'x-app' });
     </script>
   </dom-module>
   ```

   Now, `x-bar` would be notified of all changes to the `items` array (when an item is added/removed).

```js
HTMLImports.whenReady(() => {
  "use strict";

  Polymer({
    is: 'x-app'
  });
  
  Polymer({
    is: 'x-foo',
    properties: {
      items: {
        type: Array,
        value: function() { return []; },
        notify: true
      }
    },

    _addItem: function() {
      this.push('items', {name: 'item' + this.items.length});
    }
  });
  
  Polymer({
    is: 'x-bar',
    properties: {
      items: {
        type: Array
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.6.0/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
</head>
<body>
  <x-app></x-app>

  <dom-module id="x-app">
    <template>
      <x-foo items="{{items}}"></x-foo>
      <x-bar items="[[items]]"></x-bar>
    </template>
  </dom-module>
  <dom-module id="x-foo">
    <template>
      <h2><code>x-foo</code></h2>
      <button on-tap="_addItem">Add item</button>
    </template>
  </dom-module>
  <dom-module id="x-bar">
    <template>
      <h2><code>x-bar</code></h2>
      <ul>
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[items]]">
          <li>[[item.name]]</li>
        </template>
      </ul>
    </template>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/QKdqEk?editors=1010)